# How to move data from one table to another and update foreign keys (T-SQL 2008)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have two tables Blobs and FileContents which store file contents. 
Both tables have identical structure: Id int IDENTITY(1,1), Content varbinary(max) NULL,
Both table have data in it.

I have several other tables which have foreign keys to these tables.
For example table MxdFiles has field BlobId which is foreign key to Id field of Blobs table.

Now I need to move all records from Blobs to FileContents and update MxdFiles table with new Ids

Please advise how this can be achieved or provide any links to read.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
CREATE DATABASE TestDB
GO
USE TestDB;
GO
CREATE TABLE t1(ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,SomeContent VARCHAR(100));
CREATE TABLE t2(ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,SomeContent VARCHAR(100));

INSERT INTO t1 VALUES('Test1a'),('Test1b');
INSERT INTO t2 VALUES('Test2a'),('Test2b');

CREATE TABLE Referenced(ID INT IDENTITY, t1_ID INT CONSTRAINT fkTest FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES t1(ID));

INSERT INTO Referenced VALUES(1),(2); --Now both entries in t1 are referenced
```

--Want to shift all entries from t1 into t2:

```
ALTER TABLE t2 ADD OldID INT;
INSERT INTO t2
SELECT t1.SomeContent,t1.ID FROM t1;

SELECT * FROM t2;
```

--The result: imported rows have an `OldID`

```
ID  SomeContent OldID
1   Test2a      NULL
2   Test2b      NULL
3   Test1a      1
4   Test1b      2
```

--Switch the values:

```
--Drop the constraint
ALTER TABLE Referenced DROP CONSTRAINT fkTest;
--Switch the references
WITH updateableCTE aS
(
    SELECT r.t1_ID AS OldValue
          ,t2.ID AS NewValue
    FROM Referenced AS r
    INNER JOIN t2 ON r.t1_ID=t2.OldId
)
UPDATE updateableCTE SET OldValue=NewValue;
--Re-create the FK
ALTER TABLE Referenced ADD CONSTRAINT fkTest FOREIGN KEY (t1_ID) REFERENCES t2(ID); 

SELECT * FROM Referenced;

GO
USE master;
GO
DROP DATABASE TestDB;
```

Comment: Hi. Is it even allowed to do "UPDATE updateableCTE SET OldValue=NewValue;" What does it update? Is not updateableCTE a temporary table?

Comment: @AlexanderBartash, no, a CTE is often mistaken as *temporary table*, but it is just *ad-hoc* sql. It will update against its own result set as long as this is unambiguous. Just try this code...

Comment: Thank you @Shnugo This feature seems to be poorly documented because I've checked documentation for transact-sql and postrgesql and nothing there about it.

By any chance do you have any documentation for that? I am interested how it works under the hood.

Comment: @AlexanderBartash, you can read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62659552). No doc but some background.

Comment: I've tried it in Postgres and it does not allow me to update CTE. So probably it works only in specific databases.

Comment: @AlexanderBartash, sorry, no experience with this...