# Understanding CTE Semicolon Placement

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, common-table-expression

When I run this CTE in SQL Server it says the syntax is incorrect by the `declare` statement.

```
;WITH cte as
(
SELECT tblKBFolders.FolderID
from tblKBFolders
where FolderID = @FolderID

UNION ALL

SELECT tblKBFolders.FolderID
FROM tblKBFolders  
INNER JOIN cte
ON cte.FolderID = tblKBFolders.ParentFolderID
)

declare @tblQueryFolders as table (FolderID uniqueidentifier)
insert into @tblQueryFolders
SELECT FolderID From cte;
```

But if I move the `declare` to before the CTE, it runs just fine.

```
declare @tblQueryFolders as table (FolderID uniqueidentifier)

;WITH cte as
(
SELECT tblKBFolders.FolderID
from tblKBFolders
where FolderID = @FolderID

UNION ALL

SELECT tblKBFolders.FolderID
FROM tblKBFolders  
INNER JOIN cte
ON cte.FolderID = tblKBFolders.ParentFolderID
)

insert into @tblQueryFolders
SELECT FolderID From cte;
```

Why is that?

Comment: It's nothing to do with semicolon placement. The first example has the `declare` statement in the middle of a data statement (between the CTEs and the `insert`).

Comment: What are you looking for in an answer, other than "that's the way it's designed"?

Comment: Also, the semicolon is a terminator, not a 'beginator'. Don't start your CTE with a semicolon, but do end the statement before your CTE with a semicolon.

Comment: @HoneyBadger Yes, I understand that. I've seen a lot of examples written that way for some reason....

Comment: @HoneyBadger Well, I've seen in T-SQL apart from this example with CTEs that I can put declare statements wherever I like and it doesn't seem to matter, as long as, of course, I declare something before I use it. So I could put every declare at the top of the query, or declare things as they make sense for each step. Based on AlwaysLearning's comment, am I to understand that the `WITH` block is connected to the next SQL statement that follows it, and it's not just a definition of the CTE to be used at any later time, again and again?

Comment: No, a CTE is not like a variable you can declare and use wherever you want. A CTE is an expression, nothing more. The CTE and the SELECT are indeed tied.

Comment: @HoneyBadger Ah, gotcha. Maybe it was a stupid mistake, but that was indeed where I went wrong lol. If you want to add that as an answer, I'll mark it as Accepted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer you ask for was given in a comment already: This has nothing to do with the semicolon's placement.

Important: The CTE's `WITH` cannot follow right after a statement without an ending semicolon. There are many statments, where a `WITH`-clause would add something to the end of the statement (query hints, the `WITH` after `OPENJSON` etc.). The engine would have to guess, whether this `WITH` adds to the statment before or if it is a CTE's start. That's the reason, why we often see

```
;WITH cte AS (...)
```

That's actually the wrong usage of a semicolon. People put it there, just not to forget about it. Anyway it is seen as better style and *best practice* to end T-SQL statements **always** with a semicolon (and do **not** use `;WITH`, as it adds an empty statement actually).

A CTE is not much more than syntactical sugar. Putting the CTE's code within a `FROM(SELECT ...) AS SomeAlias` would be roughly the same. In most cases this would lead to the same execution plan. It helps in cases, where you'd have to write the same `FROM(SELECT ) AS SomeAlias` in multiple places. And - in general - it makes things easier to read and understand. But it is not - by any means - comparable to a temp table or a table variable. The engine will treat it as inline code and you can use it in the same statement exclusively.

So this is the same:

```
WITH SomeCTE AS(...some query here...)
SELECT SomeCTE.* FROM SomeCTE;


SELECT SomeAlias.* 
FROM (...some query here...) AS SomeAlias;
```

Your example looks like you think of the CTE as kind of a *temp table definition*, which you can use in the following statements. But this is not correct.

After the CTE the engine expects another CTE or a final statement like `SELECT` or `UPDATE`.

```
WITH SomeCTE AS(...some query here...)
SELECT * FROM SomeCTE;
```

or

```
WITH SomeCTE AS( ...query... )
    ,AnotherCTE AS ( ...query... )
SELECT * FROM AnotherCTE;
```

...or another content added with the `WITH` clause:

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES( ...namespace declarations...)
    ,SomeCTE AS( ...query... )
SELECT * FROM SomeCTE;
```

All of these examples are **one single statement**.

Putting a `DECLARE @Something` in the middle, would break this concept.